# On the HSK5 exam, if you're asked to use a separable verb in a sentence, can you separate it?

Tags: chinese, hsk

Question 99 on the HSK5 exam asks you to write an approximately 80-character snippet using 5 given words.  A typical example looks like this:

> [image: Example question 99 with the words 结帐、干脆、感谢、临时、海鲜]

Here, we see the separable verb 结帐, so we can write sentences where 结 and 帐 are separated, such as:

> 我总是先整理**结**了**帐**的房间，除非您有要求。  ([source](http://www.jukuu.com/show-%E7%BB%93+%E5%B8%90-1.html))

I'm not sure if this counts as using the word 结帐, it depends on how strict the rules are here.

**Question**: On the HSK5 exam, if you're asked to use a separable verb in a sentence, can you separate it?